# How can I detect buffering in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, video, avplayer

I have a streaming video app, and I would like to know how I can detect whether the app is buffering or not.

In AVPlayer, there is the `currentItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp` boolean that tells you when the playback buffer is likely to keep up at the current download speed, and `currentItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty` that tells you when the playback buffer is empty.

The problem occurs when the video is playing, the video pauses because the internet is too slow. If I then press the play button, the `rate` of the player is 1, but it is not playing.

How can I detect that the video is paused because it is buffering? `currentItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty` is true even when the video is playing...

EDIT: I have combined these 2 and now the loader I show to display buffering is only shown if `currentItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty && !currentItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp`, the loader now only shows a few seconds after the video starts playing.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine for me, maybe it can help, call `self?.bufferState()` inside `addPeriodicTimeObserver`

```
    private func bufferState() {
    if let currentItem = self.avPlayer.currentItem {
        if currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay {
            if currentItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
                print("Playing ")
            } else if currentItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty {
                print("Buffer empty - show loader")
            }  else if currentItem.isPlaybackBufferFull {
                print("Buffer full - hide loader")
            } else {
                print("Buffering ")
            }
        } else if currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.failed {
            print("Failed ")
        } else if currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.unknown {
            print("Unknown ")
        }
    } else {
        print("avPlayer.currentItem is nil")
    }
}
```